# Re-sizing and adding grid rows on window resize dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

I have a group box with a grid. Right now the grid has 2 columns and 8 rows.

Grid row 0 column 0 has a combo box.
Grid row 0 column 1 has a text box.

The rest of the grid rows are empty. When the program is running the user clicks a button and the rest of the rows are filled dynamically one by one with each button click with combo boxes and text boxes respectively.

Grid row 1 column 0 has a combo box.
Grid row 1 column 1 has a text box.

Grid row 2 column 0 has a combo box.
Grid row 2 column 1 has a text box.

Grid row # column 0 has a combo box.
Grid row # column 1 has a text box.

Until it reaches the last row.

This is my button click function:

```
    int c = 1;
    private void AddNewNum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        txt.Name = "txtList1PhoneNum"+c;
        txt.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        txt.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        txt.Margin = new Thickness(8, 7, 0, 0);
        txt.Height = 26;
        txt.Width = 120;
        Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(txt, c);
        List1.Children.Add(txt);

        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmb = new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox();
        cmb.Name = "cmbList1PhoneNum" + c;
        cmb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        cmb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        cmb.Margin = new Thickness(7, 7, 0, 0);
        cmb.Height = 26;
        cmb.Width = 118;
        Grid.SetColumn(cmb, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(cmb, c);
        List1.Children.Add(cmb);

        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txt2 = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        txt2.Name = "txtList2PhoneNum" + c;
        txt2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        txt2.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        txt2.Margin = new Thickness(8, 7, 0, 0);
        txt2.Height = 26;
        txt2.Width = 120;
        Grid.SetColumn(txt2, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(txt2, c);
        List2.Children.Add(txt2);

        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmb2 = new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox();
        cmb2.Name = "cmbList2PhoneNum" + c;
        cmb2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        cmb2.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        cmb2.Margin = new Thickness(7, 7, 0, 0);
        cmb2.Height = 26;
        cmb2.Width = 118;
        Grid.SetColumn(cmb2, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(cmb2, c);
        List2.Children.Add(cmb2);

        c++;
    }
```

_

What I want to achieve is that I don't want the rows to have a limit, I want the grid to grow dynamically with each button click either by adding new rows to grid and re-sizing the window dynamically, or adding new rows to grid and having a scroll bar when it exceeds the group box's height limit.

Comment: Delete all that ugly code and use proper XAML and Databinding.

Comment: @HighCore Thanx for nothing! I'm still learning -_- !

Comment: Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListView with a template containing a Combobox and a TextBox. Bind the ListView to a list in your view model. When you click add a new item to the list in your view model and a new row will appear

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx), [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) control. Also take a look at how DataTamplets work. Simple example just to get started how it should look like.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemComboSource}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```